# how to connect to a peer computer on same network using blackberry

Tags: java, networking, blackberry, device-discovery

i want to develop an application for my Blackberry smart phone that scans the WIFI network on which i am currently connected and show me a list of connected hosts (PCs), i also want to browse the files shared on those machine (obviously only those whom i am allowed to see) & transfer them to my device from the remote machine or to remote machine from my device.

How it can be done, any guidelines?

Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Cool history lesson... is Blackberry still in use out there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Blackberry API does not have support for file sharing you are basically talking about writing a SMB or NFS client (depending on the flavour of the shared storage you want to access). Unless you've already done this kind of programming, you are probably better off to seek out an existing solution; the Blackberry API isn't the arena I would recommend learning advanced network programming in.